# PlayN GWT hosted mode BufferOverflowException

Tags: gwt, nio, playn, gwt-hosted-mode

I'm trying to get the PlayN demos and show cases to work in eclipse.

When i build / run the "Cute" sample using **maven** :

```
/path-to/playn-samples/cute$ mvn -Phtml integration-test
```

it works fine and i get to see the demo on *http://localhost:8080/*

But when i run GWT inside eclipse in **hosted mode**, it seems to compile fine, but once in the browser (*http://127.0.0.1:8888/CuteGame.html?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997*) i get an  error in FireBug console (keeps repeating until i close the browser tab)

```
uncaught exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Native buffer required java.nio.DirectFloatBufferU[pos=0 lim=640 cap=640]
uncaught exception: java.nio.BufferOverflowException
```

Any idea what this could be ?

Edit: Here are the versions i'm using:

- PlayN 1.4
- GWT 2.4
- Eclipse Indigo
- FireFox 13.0.1
- Java 6
- Windows 7, 64bits
- Hosted mode works fine for other projets.

Comment: I'm having the same issue in my project, reverting from 1.4 to 1.3 seems to be a workaround. I don't have time to look into it right now, hope you find an answer though.

Comment: thank you for the tip, i'll downgrade to version 1.3 and give it a try

Comment: Yep, reverting to 1.3 solved the problem, but the game is extremely slow when on hosted mode. Not sure if it's normal behavior?

Comment: GWT hosted mode is always slow compared to production mode, it's suggested to debug in the Java build instead: http://code.google.com/p/playn/wiki/GameDebuggingOptions